# Lightbox - Have 1 image link to a gallery

Tags: jquery, lightbox, lightbox2

I have this lightbox gallery:

```
<div class="image-row">
                                <div class="image-set">
                                        <a class="example-image-link" href="img/demopage/image-3.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Click the right half of the image to move forward."><img class="example-image" src="img/demopage/thumb-3.jpg" alt=""/></a>
                                        <a class="example-image-link" href="img/demopage/image-4.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Or press the right arrow on your keyboard."><img class="example-image" src="img/demopage/thumb-4.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                        <a class="example-image-link" href="img/demopage/image-5.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="The next image in the set is preloaded as you're viewing."><img class="example-image" src="img/demopage/thumb-5.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                        <a class="example-image-link" href="img/demopage/image-6.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Click anywhere outside the image or the X to the right to close."><img class="example-image" src="img/demopage/thumb-6.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                </div>
                        </div>
```

but this displays all the image thumbnails, I am looking to have 1 image and when you click on it, the user is able to go through all images....I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Have you tried using CSS to hide the `.example-image-link` links that you don't want?

Answer (score -1):

Just replace `example-set` to `example-1` for the 1st image, and
`example-set` to `example-2` for the 2nd image in the same page